# Sort divs based on array order and add a title and count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html that looks like the following:

```
<div id="mainboard">
    <div id="card"><div class="price">20</div><div class="style">blue</div></div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">23</div><div class="style">red</div></div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">10</div><div class="style">red</div></div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">29</div><div class="style">green</div></div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">35</div><div class="style">blue</div></div>
</div>
```

This is what I currently have:

```
function SortDivs(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
    var colorOrder = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
        var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();

        console.log(vA+', '+vB);

        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}
```

If I do this:

```
SortDivs($('#mainboard'), 'div', 'div.style');
```

I get:

```
<div id="mainboard">
    <div id="card"><div class="price">20</div><div class="style">blue</div></div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">35</div><div class="style">blue</div></div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">29</div><div class="style">green</div></div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">23</div><div class="style">red</div></div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">10</div><div class="style">red</div></div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so the results look like this:
(Note the custom color order and it counts the rows per category.)

```
<div id="mainboard">
    <div id="title">Red (2)</div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">23</div><div class="style">red</div></div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">10</div><div class="style">red</div></div>
    <div id="title">Blue (2)</div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">20</div><div class="style">blue</div></div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">35</div><div class="style">blue</div></div>
    <div id="title">Green (1)</div>
    <div id="card"><div class="price">29</div><div class="style">green</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fixed the example code.

Comment: It's just example code, that's not even the point of the question.

Comment: That's why I'm here to get some help.

Comment: My real code has a lot more than that. I can extrapolate the answer to fit my needs if it can solve the above.

Comment: Yes, and provide row count for each color.

Comment: I’ve cleared my comments. The below answer does the sorting right, only the row count is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete rework of your code so I'll leave it to you to rebuild it into a function.

It wraps the colors in new div with title in the array order shown, and sorts each color by price

```
// variable setup
var $styles = $('.style'),
    colorOrder = ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
    $main = $('#mainboard');
    // loop over colors to find matching elements
    $.each(colorOrder, function (_, color) {
        var $wrapper = $('<div>');
        var $colorStyle= $styles.filter(function () {
            return $(this).text() == color;
        });        

       $colorStyle.parent().sort(function (a, b) {
            var priceA = +$(a).find('.price').text(),
                priceB = +$(b).find('.price').text();

            return priceA > priceB ? 1 : (priceA < priceB ? 0 : -1);
        }).appendTo($wrapper);
        $wrapper.prepend('<h3>' + color + ' ('+ $colorStyle.length + ')</h3>');            

        $main.append($wrapper);
    });
```

Would be a little more efficient using the colors as classes or data attributes on the parent of the style as well as data attribute for price...would cut out a bit of this chain

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c9cp64jo/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll go test for a sec.

Comment: The row count for the title is incorrect. For example, <div id="title">Red (2)</div> that (2) is indicating how many rows have <div class="style">red</div>. In the demo you provided, it's currently displaying price values.

Comment: @rotaercz I didn't add row count at all...will ad now...just take a second

Comment: A lot of these values in my html are display:none; I thought you thought that I wanted price values instead of row count.

Comment: Adjusted answer for row counts. Not sure what you mean about the price...I matched the example you gave

Comment: I'll go test. I'll be back. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

and change

```
var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
```

to

```
var vA = colorOrder.indexOf($(keySelector, a).text());
var vB = colorOrder.indexOf($(keySelector, b).text());
```

This will give you a value based on the position in the array.

Comment: Is there a way to add a title div and get the row count too?

Comment: Sure, you can add some classes while sorting. Then use a selector to select all elements of that class and prepend some html.

Comment: What's a good way to get the row count without having to count all the divs everytime for every category?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `id`s to `class`es, because `id`s must be unique.

You can then use this code:

```js
function SortDivs(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
  var colorOrder = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

  $.each(colorOrder, function(_, color) {
    var ch=
      parent.find(keySelector).filter(function() {
        return $(this).text()===color
      }).parent().appendTo(parent);
      
    ch.first().before('<div class="title">'+color+' ('+ch.length+')</div>');
  });
}

SortDivs($('#mainboard'), 'div', 'div.style');
```

```css
.title {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.price, .style {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainboard">
    <div class="card"><div class="price">20</div><div class="style">blue</div></div>
    <div class="card"><div class="price">23</div><div class="style">red</div></div>
    <div class="card"><div class="price">10</div><div class="style">red</div></div>
    <div class="card"><div class="price">29</div><div class="style">green</div></div>
    <div class="card"><div class="price">35</div><div class="style">blue</div></div>
</div>
```